# Primefaces columns resize is not working on tables with horizontal scrollbar

Tags: primefaces

I'm developing a dynamic datatable with Primefaces 6.0, there are 15 columns. Columns are not resizable as long as there is a horizontal scroll bar. 
If I use fewer columns so that no horizontal scroll bar appears, columns resize is working.
Is there any possibility to resize columns in tables with horizontal scrollbars?

Comment: First, try to find the "resize cursor" along the header, but not neccesarily between the columns. If that doesn't work for you, try to put the dataTable inside a collapsed panel, I know that this is not the best solution, but it might work.